# MariaDB Excessive memory Usage

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a Quad Core Processor based 16 GiG RAM and 4 TB HDD for DB and 4 TB for OS.
The bufferpool allocated is 6 GB. Tried with 70% of memory too but result is same.
The memory is getting filled up very quickly. When I am restarting the service it is freed but in say less than 20 minutes 10-15% is getting filled.

My my.conf config:

```
[client]
socket=/db/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
datadir=/db/mysql
socket=/db/mysql/mysql.sock

innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 6
thread_cache_size = 4
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
query_cache_type = 0
innodb_fast_shutdown=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
```

Attaching my memory usage graph too.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Important References:

Show Variables - [pastebin.com/wzAhva55](http://pastebin.com/wzAhva55) 
Show global status - [pastebin.com/8G1N3g78](http://pastebin.com/8G1N3g78)

Comment: Some more information would be useful, e.g. buffer pool/memory section from SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS. Does the slow query log contains some information, e.g. slow queries using sort buffer? Any long running processes in SHOW PROCESSLIST ?

Comment: InnoDB Satus - http://pastebin.com/Hxi6S5f8
Show ProcessList - http://pastebin.com/ftTiDSrC

Output was too long, so had to use pastebin.

Comment: What is the meaning and units of the Y axix on the graphs?

Comment: Are other apps running on the same server?

Comment: Please provide (via pastebin) `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` after it has been up several hours.

Comment: @RickJames - X Axis - Represents Time
Y Axis - System Memory Utilization.
No other APP is running on the server other than DB

Comment: Show Variables - http://pastebin.com/wzAhva55
Show global status - http://pastebin.com/8G1N3g78

Comment: Impressive:  308K queries per second!  Lots of stored routines?  (More analysis to come.)

Comment: @RickJames : You have done a brilliant analysis. I will apply one by one.Basically this server receives receives a huge amount of data (logs) constantly and the SP immediately process those RAW data into Useful information and stores in tables which can be searched later.

Answer (score 4):

**Observations:**

```
Version: **5.5.50-MariaDB**
**16 GB** of RAM
Uptime = **3d 05:16:26**
You are **not** running on Windows.
Running **64-bit** version
You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) **InnoDB**.
20 issues flagged, out of 145 computed Variables/Status/Expressions checked
```

**The More Important Issues**

- Since you have a "smallish" 6G for the buffer_pool, it is puzzling why the RAM is so full.
- No replication is involved, correct?
- Why is `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct` set to zero?  Normally it is 75 (%).  I would expect you to suffer a lot of I/O.
- The iblogs are rotating extremely rapidly.  This is because of high activity, together with an exremely tiny `log_file_size = 5M`.  Change that to 1G; but caution:  Changing it is complicated and involves a restart.
- 6K tmp tables created per second.  3K table scans/sec.  These imply that some indexes or query tuning might be useful.
- You seem to have a very low turnover in connections, so the comments below about threads and connections are probably not important.
- `Aborted_connects` / `Connections` = 98.8% .  (Up to 20% is 'ok'.)

Do you have a RAM disk?  How big?  I typically argue against such.  However, if you have a RAM disk, that would explain the high memory usage, high query rate, and yet seeming low I/O problem.

**Details and other observations**

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size / _ram ) = 6,442,450,944 / 16384M = 37.5%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool

`( open_files_limit ) = 1,024` -- ulimit -n
-- To allow more files, change ulimit or /etc/security/limits.conf or in sysctl.conf (kern.maxfiles & kern.maxfilesperproc) or something else (OS dependent)  On the other hand, `Open_table*` values are very low, so it seems you are using very few tables.

`( innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct ) = 0` -- When buffer_pool starts flushing to disk
-- Are you experimenting?

`( Innodb_log_writes ) = 26,966,874 / 278186 = 97 /sec`

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 253,091,451,392 / (278186 / 3600) / 2 / 5M = 312`
-- Ratio

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 278,186 / 60 * 5M / 253091451392 = 0.096` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size.

`( Questions ) = 889,470,233 / 278186 = 3197 /sec` -- Queries (outside SP) -- "qps"
-- >2000 *may* be stressing server

`( Queries ) = 85,684,886,985 / 278186 = 308012 /sec` -- Queries (including inside SP)
-- >3000 *may* be stressing server

`( (Queries-Questions)/Queries ) = (85684886985-889470233)/85684886985 = 99.0%` -- Fraction of queries that are inside Stored Routines.
-- (Not bad if high; but it impacts the validity of some other conclusions.)

`( Created_tmp_tables ) = 1,674,262,702 / 278186 = 6018 /sec` -- Frequency of creating "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs.

`( Select_scan ) = 837,131,930 / 278186 = 3009 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 837,131,930 / 2511393099 = 33.3%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (837130735 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0) / 278186 = 3009 /sec` -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of normal drives

`( expire_logs_days ) = 0` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin = OFF)

`( long_query_time ) = 10.000000 = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Aborted_connects / Connections ) = 11,455 / 11594 = 98.8%` -- Perhaps a hacker is trying to break in?

`( thread_cache_size ) = 4` -- How many extra processes to keep around (Not relevant when using thread pooling) (Autosized as of 5.6.8; based on max_connections)

**More**

`Select_scan / Com_select` is so close to 1/3 as to be suspicious that you have a strong pattern in the queries performed.  Perhaps there is repetition that could be avoided?  Similarly, `Com_set_option/Queries` is very close to 1/6.

`Handler_read*` values are extremely small compared to the number of queries.

Hmmm...  `Select_scan`/sec, `Com_call_procedure`/sec, and `Com_insert`/sec are all very similar (3009/sec).  Only one procedure, and it is called a lot?

`Innodb_rows_inserted` = 622 /sec.

Sorry, much of this analysis aims at performance, not memory.  I did come up with one memory thought.  I would guess the ramdisk is 4-5G?

Comment: As I increased buffer pool to 10G from 6G memory usage rose to 98%. So again reverted back to 6G. Made innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct to default. Cannot change innodb_log_file_size = 1G in my.cnf as it is giving error.

Comment: Do you have a ramdisk?

Comment: From df -h there are tmpfs as 7.7 GB. Attached screenshot along with main question. But I have not created any of this. it was all there by default. (sdc is my DB drive)

Comment: Assuming that /dev/shm is a ramdisk, then that 7.7GB is not available as RAM for caches, such as the buffer_pool.  Hence 6G is about the limit in (16 - 7.7)GB.  Put another way:  You are using (7.7 + 6 + miscellany) GB, hence the big graphs.  Why does the graph drop to near zero?  Maybe tmpfs was unmounted then?

Comment: The graphs drops to zero when i do a manual restart of mariadb service. How to get around the RAM disk thing? Is it really necessary for the OS ?

Comment: Can you explain the uses of "tmpfs" in the screenshot?